# Redirigir trafico https to http

Tags: docker, apache2, nextcloud

he creado mi propia nube, este es el escenario que tengo:

Proxmox 7.0.1 -> LXC Debian 10 -> Docker.

Al principio tenia una maquina virtual y NFS, pero el contenedor tenia SQLlite y era muy lento en un solo contenedor.
Ahora tengo dos contenedores

1)
nextcloud   "/entrypoint.sh apac…"   3 hours ago   Up 3 hours   0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp, :::8080->80/tcp   nextcloud_app_1

2)
mariadb     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   3 hours ago   Up 3 hours   3306/tcp                                nextcloud_db_1

una es la BBDD y la otra es la APP con apache2.

Accedo a mi nube por http://nextcloud.midominio.io:37111

Tengo una redireccion de puertos en mi router, por eso uso el puerto 37111.

Ahora que tengo mi dominio y quiero instalar la api de google, no tengo claro como poder poner https en mi nextCloud.

Tengo que exponer los puertos 443 de mi contenedor? como se hace esto?
No puedo instalar algun "proxy" que me haga de redireccion.

por ejemplo => https://172.10.0.100:443 -> http://172.10.0.100:8080

estoy muy perdido como hacer esto con docker, por eso tengo muchas ideas pero ahora que funciona mi contenedor muy bien ya me da miedo cargarmelo.

muchas gracias!!